# Excel VBA Clear Active Cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I am needing to do a few things, the first is run a macro when the delete key is pressed, so I found this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "Intercept"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}"
End Sub
```

Now according to what I read, this will in turn make the delete key useless so I also need it to clear the currently active cell at the same time, I found this:

```
Sub SetValue()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = 35
End Sub
```

and this:

```
Selection.Clear
```

However, I am a new to VBA so I don't really know how to combine these to use the clear function on delete :).. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You may want to check out the worksheet_change event, once you have that figured out, you can use target. So if you delete a cell, that cell becomes the target and if target="" then do something.

Comment: Thanks, I already have some stuff set up to work with that, didn't think to try adding anything else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second part of OnKey call "Intercept" is the name of the sub you have to add in a regular module.

you just have to right-click on Modules > insert > module and add the sub like this :

Worksheet code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "deleteAction"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{DELETE}"
End Sub
```

Module code :

```
Sub deleteAction()
    Selection.Clear
    [... the few things you have to do :) ...]
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!

I did have to change "Clear" to "ClearContents" so it would keep the formatting, then I just added in the rest of the code I needed to run and it seems to do exactly what I need.

Oh I also had to change "DELETE" to "DEL" or it wouldn't recognize my keypress.

Answer (score 1):

To set an active cell value, you can use this function in your module:

```
Sub SetValue()
  ActiveCell = Null ' to clear the contents
End Sub
```

or you can use your code from the OP.

`Worksheet_Activate()` and `Worksheet_Deactivate` are `Workbook` functions. In your VBAProject, double-click `ThisWorkbook` and change "General" to "Workbook" in the dropdown on top. Then, in the drop-down on the right, you can select `SheetActivate` and `SheetDeativate`. Add these functions and fill out with your code to disable *DELETE* key on your `Sheet1` worksheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "SetValue"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
' This will enable DELETE
  If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then Application.OnKey "{DELETE}"
End Sub
```

To disable any processing when DELETE is pressed, specify `""` as a 2nd argument to `OnKey`. And only pass the key name without the 2nd argument to enable processing (see [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx)).

P.S. This might trigger only after switching to the worksheet being handled.